# Connectons API: Posting on behalf of others / Impersonation

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm currently implementing a solution, where an external tool is making posts to the Connections API. These calls are made via basic authentication with a service account configured in the external tool.

However, I need the posted content in Connections to appear as posted by another user than the service account (users ids/emails are known to the external tool). Is there any way, the service account can post on behalf of others/impersonate users when posting to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add support for your the external user account to the right websphere roles

These Application / Roles are: 
WidgetContainer trustedExternalApplication, admin

You can follow this article to set it up on your system.

In order to give a user administrative access to widgets, we can assign some privileges to one of the users - fadams.

You need to start the deployment manager on the quickstart.

Connect to the system via SSH
sudo /etc/init.d/ConServer_DM_was.init start

Navigate to https://${HOSTNAME}:9044/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure
Enter User ID : wasadmin
Enter Password : lcsecret
Click Login

Expand Applications > Application Types
Click on WebSphere Enterprise Applications

Select one of the Applications (from the table)

Application     Role 
Homepage     admin 
WidgetContainer trustedExternalApplication admin 
Communities     widget-admin admin 
Profiles     admin

Click on Homepage

Click on "Security role to user/group mapping"

Select One of the Roles (Admin)

Click Map Users

Enter Search String - fadams
Click Search
Click the Right Arrow
Click Ok

Click Ok

Click Save

Repeat for Each Application and Each Role in the Table Above

....

Click System Administration on the Left
Click on Nodes
Check localhostNode01
Click Synchronize

The Servers are now synchronized with your updates to the roles.

Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers
Check conServer
Click Restart

Once you see the Green arrow again, the connections server is fully restarted

Navigate to https://${HOSTNAME}:444/homepage
Login as fadams with your password

You should see administration on the left side of your connections instance

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/How_to_update_the_quickstart_to_support_Widgets

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have a user set up as trustedExternalApplication, but how does impersonation work then? Let's say I want to make a blog post in the name of another user: The API documentation (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Blog_posting_content_ic45&content=pdcontent) says a posted author in the blog entry xml is ignored and I observe the author always being my 'service account'. How do I make sure the desired user is impersonated instead?

Comment: ok, so for activity streams trustedExternalApplication works. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Distributing_events_ic45&content=pdcontent  ... you really need to look at implemnting oauth, storing the key for oauth, and using it to authenticate access to the blog, and then you can fully act on behalf of the user.

Comment: Sadly, oauth is not really a smooth option in our case, nonetheless thanks for your answer as it fully satisfies my question. And again many thanks for always replying this quickly to arising issues, that's really appreciated!

Comment: @Paul, that URL is 404ing "HTTP Web Server: IBM Notes Exception - Entry not found in index"

Comment: I added the steps inline.